# Copying conditional formats

Tags: conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

I have conditional formats with ranges like this:

```
A:A
B:B
C:C
D:D
E:E
F:F
```

But when I duplicate the sheet, the new sheet has ranges like this:

```
A:A
B:B,C:E
F:F
```

Is there a way to fix or work around this problem? If not, is there a way to easily copy the conditional formats from the original sheet to the new sheet?